# Create a function within a function

Tags: r, function

**How to make a function within a function?**

My goal is to insert the function inside the  function.

Comment: Thanks for the edit BM14. Is it correct that the error function will take arguments of the observed and predicted values from the lm model?

Comment: Yes user20650. Is it possible to have that kind of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of function inside a function

```
f <- function(n) {
  g <- function(x) {
    x**n
  }
}
```

such that

```
> f(3)(4)
[1] 64
```

But I have no idea what you are exactly after...

Comment: I'm doing a temperature function within a plot function. I hope, it works properly. Thank You for the answer

Comment: @G.Grothendieck:  I didn't downvote, but it's not generally good style to name your return value.  It just obscures what the function is doing.  (One exception is where `g()` needs to refer to itself recursively, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: If that is someone's opinion fine but I am sure many others disagree with such a style and in any case it does not merit  a downvote.